# missing file operand cp after su

Tags: linux, ubuntu, copy, cp, su

I run this command on ubuntu:

```
su - test -c cp /home/test/toto.txt /home/test/dir
```

But I have this error!

```
cp: missing file operand
```

anyone has an idea about the problem?
 thank you

Comment: If I were to say, "use sudo instead of su", that wouldn't help would it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option `-c` is understood by command `su`, taking the *next* argument (not the remaining) to be the command.  That next command is just `cp`.

Try putting the command into quotes:

```
su - test -c 'cp /home/test/toto.txt /home/test/dir'
```

If this is problematic because you want to have quotes inside the command, try using escape *instead* of the inner quotes:

```
su - test -c 'echo hello\ \ there'
```

Comment: You mean like that?:
su - test cp /home/test/toto.txt /home/test/dir